# How do you add item subtotal and grand totals to the packing slip pdf?

Tags: pdf, shipment, packing-slip

I'd like to list the item subtotal for the items, and then the grand total beneath - much like the invoice PDF does.

I'm failing to tackle both problems:

1. I've edited `/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Shipment/Default.php` from the invoice example but unfortunately `$priceData['subtotal']` is zero.

   It appears to me this is because that higher up the stack I need to be adding various calls but it feels wrong to be duplicating so much code when the invoice object has this info already.
2. Simply adding `$this->insertTotals($page, $shipment);` just lists zeros, presumably because the subTotals mentioned in -1- are zero.

---

Can someone help direct me to a solution please?

Answer (score 1):

As you have found out there is no easy solution. As it is Magento simply does not calculate any totals for the shipment (which the packing slip pdf is based on). For example if you compare on the database level the tables `sales_flat_shipment` to `sales_flat_invoice` you will notice that the shipment does not include any currency amounts.

If you wanted to tackle this completely you would need to do a lot of things including

1. adding the required database fields to both `sales_flat_shipment`
   and `sales_flat_shipment_item`
2. write the code that actually runs the total calculation - if you
   look into app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml

   you will find  global/sales/quote/totals
   global/sales/order_invoice/totals
   global/sales/order_creditmemo/totals
   but again nothing for
   shipments. You would need to implement the calculation classes for
   each new total as well.
3. once the above is done you could then pull in the numbers into the
   packing slip pdf like you have already done

If, and only if, you are always shipping all ordered items you could use a shortcut. Instead of printing the packing slip based on the shipment object you could print the packing slip based on the order item (this way you have access to the calculated figures).

Changing
`$this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);`

to
`$this->_drawItem($item->getOrderItem(), $page, $order);`

in Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Shipment should give you a starting point.